# libcURL inconsistent when POSTing

Tags: c, libcurl

When I post to a certain URL via libcURL most of the time the status code will be a 401, but sometimes it will return the 200 I expect even though the credentials I pass are the same. The weird thing is that if I use the same code ported to python and using urllib2 I will get a 200 ok and I will get the data I need. Here is the relevant code that I am using to post to the website. libcURL also works fine for me to get the needed credentials for this function such as the xut_sid key and cookie, it is just this url that sometimes 401s and sometimes 200s.

```
CURL *curl_handle;
CURLcode res;
struct curl_slist *header = NULL;
MemoryStruct chunk;
...

header = curl_slist_append(header, l->cookie);// l just contains the data I need
header = curl_slist_append(header, l->xut_sid);
header = curl_slist_append(header, "Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8");
header = curl_slist_append(header, "x-http-method-override: GET");

curl_handle = curl_easy_init();
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, searchString);
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, header);
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteMemoryCallback);
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &chunk);


res = curl_easy_perform(curl_handle);
```

EDIT: I fixed it, twas a dumb mistake by me where the xut_sid would get overwritten(I'm new to C lol and didn't use strdup to copy the string) and not be sent. I don't know why it showed up in the verbose log as there, but it wasn't being sent.

Comment: I sse that you are setting libcurl to verbose, so you should be able to see exactly what your client is sending to the server. Otherwise, take a look with tcpdump/wireshark, and verify that you are sending the same request that the one sent by python.

Comment: Yeah it turns out that one of the headers wasn't being sent all the time but it was being shown in the verbose logs. It was still s dumb mistake by me though.